# Restart-ability in pentaho community edition

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am using pentaho 5.2 community edition for both my production environment and aware that there is no restartability (Checkpoint) in pentaho community edition. How do i setup restartability in pentaho community edition. Any references or link would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not such feature in CE edition.
The idea of EE restart-ability was to have separate database table (like log tables - that exists in CE edition) and control on fail/success job entries based on this records. The gain is to automatically restart failed job entries and ability to show execution results over time.
For example - one can monitor job execution status code via console and restart job from console. In this case whole job will be restarted.
If checkpoints and restart-ability - job will be restarted from failed entry.
So if you have jobs that usually contains only one or two entries, if in case of restart-ability running time is not critical, or fail-handling implemented some other way - you may don't need this feature at all.

Once again - restart-ability only restart failed job entries. If for some case failed job entry made DB inconsistent - restart of job entry should fix it. If job entries rely on some initial state outside and initial outside state changed during job - for example some files was deleted restart will only restart job - not recover something that got unrecoverable broken.

Comment: How to Schedule a job in pentaho ETL 8.1 Community Edtion?

I need to pull record from Oracle db and push to MS SQL server using job scheduling. can you please any one explain how to create job scheduling in Pentaho ETL 8.1 Community Edition